# Dubrovnik Airport Luggage Storage

Tags: airports, luggage-storage, dubrovnik

Is there luggage storage service in Dubrovnik Airport?

If so, how much is the service and who is the operator? (The Airport authority or a contracted service provider?)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that there at the time of writing, **there is no luggage storage in Dubrovnik airport**. Various sites on the web say that the only official luggage storage service in Dubrovnik is provided by the Main Bus station. Moreover there is no mention of luggage storage on [the airport website](http://www.airport-dubrovnik.hr/index.php/en). It would therefore [Bus Croatia](http://www.buscroatia.com/bus-station-dubrovnik/) says (emphasis mine):

> #### Services provided by Dubrovnik bus station
>
> Additional to the information and sales services, passengers are provided with a luggage storage, taxi stand and newsstand. In the vicinity of the bus station you will find one of the information offices of the Dubrovnik Tourist Board.
>
> **At the bus station, you will find the only “official” luggage storage in Dubrovnik**

This is backed up by [Vidiworld](http://www.vidiworld.com/dubrovnik/guide/how-to-arrive-to-dubrovnik/) in a similar wording (emphasis mine):

> Dubrovnik’s main Main Bus Station houses a tourist information center, waiting room, **luggage storage (the only one in Dubrovnik)**, public telephones, ATM machine and a kiosk.

However, [the World Travel Guide page on Dubrovnik airport mentions left luggage facilities](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/croatia/dubrovnik-airport), and gives a contact number compatible with the airport phone number since the first three digits are the same:

> #### Luggage:
>
> Left luggage services are available, as is a lost and found service (tel: `+385 20 773 328`).

Note that this is the only web source I could find out there mentioning such services. I therefore conclude that the consensus goes against this claim. You could also try contacting the number and ask for more information.